# Построение docker container для тестов selenium

Tags: selenium, docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Собираю docker image для использования в gitlab-ci
Что я уже написал:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest as ubuntu
FROM php:8.1-cli as php
FROM node:14.15.0-stretch AS node
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:latest

COPY --from=ubuntu /bin /bin
COPY --from=php /app /app
COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node_modules
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm

# EXPOSE 4444
# EXPOSE 7900

LABEL miekrif uzvar-selenium

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Чего я хотел добиться:
У меня есть stage в .gitlab-ci.yml со след пунктами:

```
test-dev:
  stage: test
  image: miekrif/uzavr-selenium:latest
  script:
    - npm i
    - npm run prod
    - nohup /opt/bin/start-selenium-standalone.sh &
    - npx mocha tests/js/screenshots-* --timeout 50000
    - npx playwright test tests/js/pw_*
    - php artisan test
```

Чего я хочу добиться:
Данная джоба существует для тестирования кода, не смог додуматься как подругому завести selenium\standalone-chrome чтобы npx смог провести тесты ибо он ссылается на 127.0.0.1

Сейчас контейнер выдает ошибку:

```
/usr/bin/sh: /usr/bin/sh: cannot execute binary file
```

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
FROM node:14.15.0-stretch AS node
RUN npm i libnpx
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:latest as sel

USER root
#selenium copy
#COPY --from=sel /opt/bin/start-selenium-standalone.sh /opt/bin/start-selenium-standalone.sh
#COPY --from=sel /etc/supervisor/conf.d/ /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
#COPY --from=sel /opt/bin/generate_config /opt/bin/generate_config
#COPY --from=sel /opt/selenium/config.toml /opt/selenium/config.toml
#COPY --from=sel /opt/selenium/browser_name /opt/selenium/browser_name
#ENV SE_RELAX_CHECKS true
EXPOSE 4444
EXPOSE 7900

#Nodejs
#COPY --from=node / /
COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib/ /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/bin/
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm


LABEL miekrif uzvar-selenium

CMD ["bash"]
```

job

```
test-dev:
  stage: test
  image: miekrif/uzavr-selenium:latest
  script:
    - nohup /opt/bin/entry_point.sh &
    - npx mocha tests/js/screenshots-* --timeout 50000
    - npx playwright test tests/js/pw_*
    - php artisan test
```